# cannot connect deliver to iTunes connect

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I'm trying to connect fastlane-deliver to iTunes connect in vain. when I try :

```
deliver init
```

I'm getting

```
 Login to iTunes Connect (****@****.com)
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
/Users/a606099/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spaceship-0.13.0/lib/spaceship/tunes/tunes_client.rb:59:in `rescue in login_url': Could not fetch the login URL from iTunes Connect, the server might be down (RuntimeError)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when the DNS resolution fails. try to Changing the DNS server and testing it might help. or Wait for few hours then try again sometimes apple's servers might be down.

Comment: I think it's a proxy issue but I don't know how to resolve it

Comment: why you need to set proxy ?